# How do I find the given path between two vertexes with non-deterministic algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph

There is a cyclic graph with nodes `N` and edges `E`. I have a beginning node and ending node and I need to find all possible paths of length `K` between them.

The constraint `N, E < 50` pushes me to use non-determenistic algorithm, for example, recursively build a paths while their length less than `K` but it seems I am obliged to use recursive calls of function that may get the program slowed.

Could I use nested for-loop for finding all possible combinations and how does it look like?

Comment: You probably want to take a look at breadth-first search algorithm and stop at depth of K.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think nondeterministic algorithms will help you, except if you plan to do some concurrent or parallel computing.

Comment: @mrBen  Could you attach a link, please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search?

Comment: @mrBen but it seems that I can use this one only for trees, not for a cyclic graphs

Comment: In your case that would work, as you have a depth limit. If you did not have that limit, you could indeed fall in infinite loop with cyclic graphs.

Comment: @mrBen what if I get multiplied the adjacent matrix on itself till A[begin][end] == K ?

Comment: I have no idea how to use matrix with graph, but that might be a good idea regarding performance. If you are stuck with this, do not hesitate to ask another question, but including what you have already try (you can take a look at [ask]).

Comment: Ayrat, if you're worried about the speed of a recursive solution, matrix exponentiation is going to be *much* slower and *much* harder to recover the actual paths. Why don't you give BFS a try as suggested by @mrBen?